# React state value shows when printed via console.log(), but not on the webpage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am attempting to output a dollar figure within `props.usdGain` to a web page using React. The thing that's tripping me up is that the line `console.log("",props.usdGain);` succesfully puts the correct number into my console.
However, the line towards the bottom `{"Net earnings $"+props.usdGain}` displays as `undefined`.

A bizarre effect I'm seeing is that if I make any innocuous edit within my code editor (e.g. add a space or hit enter), the correct value suddenly appears on the screen. But then the moment I do a hard refresh on my browser, it goes straight back to `undefined`.

Any ideas?

P.s. Not sure if helpful, but this component is loaded via a function call with a JSX snippet in my App.js file.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';

const chart = (props) =>{
    console.log("",props.usdGain);
    return (
        <div style={{height: "500px", width: "800px"}} key={props.vaultId}>
        <Line data={props.chart} options={{
            responsive: true,
            title: {
                text: props.vaultId, 
                display: true,
                fontSize: 30
            },
            }}/>
        <p style={{color:"gray", fontSize: "18px"}}>
            {"Net earnings $"+props.usdGain}
        </p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default chart;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of how the JSX parser compiles data within curly braces. Under the hood, JSX is expecting expressions of a singular evaluation or datatype. For better comprehension, take the following as an example; when babel reads your JSX code to create a component, the below JS code is used:

`React.createElement(component, props, ...children)`

an *example*:

`<MyButton color='blue' shadowSize={2} />`

or frankly:

```
React.createElement(
  MyButton,
  {color: 'blue', shadowSize: 2},
  'Click Me'
)
```

*To break it down*, the spread operator for accepting children can not be applied to your expression. See https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html for more.

When I tried to reproduce your issue with multiple objects of any data type (i.e: two separate strings or two variables) it returned undefined/failed loudly for me. Why it failed silently for you is most likely due to JSX reading your expression as a concatenation of two values therefore when it is mapped to the DOM, you just see `undefined`.

As for your **solution** I recommend deconstructing `{"Net earnings $"+props.usdGain}` as

```
{ `Net earnings $${ +props.usdGain }` }
```

String interpolation for the win.

Let me know if this works for you as an accepted solution.

Comment: In fact, you can even create a reference to an evaluation of  

const **foo** = `Net earnings $${ +props.usdGain }`

And call  { **foo** } in your render!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time! I put my code up here. Still doesn't work sadly..  The flow goes from App.js > earningChartList.js > earningChart.js
 https://github.com/TheRyanMiller/yearn-returns/blob/a00c47a12c8dd1cd3045ea8aeabf0f8835258e75/client/src/components/earningChart.js#L17

Comment: Can you show me an example of what `props.usdGain` outputs? The logic might just have to be formatted with your numerator logic before hand. Perhaps use of `Number()`